# How can I check if a user liked a post in React, Node and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am making a social media app where users can like a post, however, I am unsure on how I can display if they have already liked it every time the page loads with different posts. I know that I would have to create a separate table with post_id and user_id, but how can I check if a post_id matches a user_id for each post (there's many)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check there is any row in `Likes` table with `post_id` of that post and `user_id` of authorized user.

```js
connection.query(
     "SELECT Count(*) AS likesCount FROM Likes WHERE user_id = '?' AND post_id = '?'",
     [user.id, post.id], (err, rows) => {
        const {likesCount} = rows[0];
        if (likesCount > 0)
            console.log(`'${user.name}' liked this post`)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would I do it for many posts efficiently when the page loads in the client side?

Comment: You should get `likesCount` for every post. in your get posts api url you can add this property in your output data.